# XSLT Template in mode output contains element supposed to be matched in other mode

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I want to process some nodes and process a subset of those nodes again, specifically those whose 'n'-ancestors have a direct child 'x'.

The XML, simplified as much as possible:

```
    <root>
        <s>
        </s>
        <s>
            <n>
                <w a="Hello"/>
                <n>
                    <x/>
                    <w a="he said"/>
                </n>
            </n>
            <n>
                <w a="how are you"/>
            </n>
        <n>
        </n>
        <n>
            <w a="she answered"/>
            <n>
                <n>
                    <x/>
                    <w a="friendly"/>
                </n>
            </n>
        </n>
    </s>
</root>
```

As I have to process some w nodes twice, I decided to use modes. I have two modes (for readability named 'fromone', 'fromtwo' here) that match the 'a-attribute' and also tried various combinations using only one mode, adding an empty template without a mode, but the result remains the same.

The relevant part of the XSLT, also simplified, the original templates mostly match on conditions (except the ones with a mode):

```
<xsl:template match="root/s">
    <output>
        <one>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::w"/>
        </one>
        <x>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="n"/>
        </x>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="n[x]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::w/@a" mode="fromtwo"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@a" mode="fromone"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@a" mode="fromtwo">
    <fromtwo>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </fromtwo>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@a" mode="fromone">
    <fromone>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </fromone>
</xsl:template>
```

I expect the output to look like this:

```
<root>
   <output>
      <one>
         <fromone>Hello</fromone>
         <fromone>he said</fromone>
         <fromone>how are you</fromone>
         <fromone>she answered</fromone>
         <fromone>friendly</fromone>
      </one>
      <x>
         <fromtwo>he said</fromtwo>
         <fromtwo>friendly</fromtwo>
      </x>
   </output>
</root>
```

But in the actual result, the node x contains elements that I expected to be only matched coming from the other template-call, to 'fromone':

```
<x>
     <fromone>Hello</fromone>
     <fromtwo>he said</fromtwo>
     <fromone>how are you</fromone>
     <fromone>she answered</fromone>
     <fromtwo>friendly</fromtwo>
  </x>
```

As this is the result I get from all XSLT processors I tried, I assume I have an error in the structure of my templates. Even after reading other posts with mode-issues I am no closer to a solution or finding my error in the XSLT.

What error did I make?

Why does the result have the mixed output of both templates instead of showing only the output of 'fromtwo'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What error did I make?

When you do:

```
   <x>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="n"/>
    </x>
```

you are applying templates to **all** `n` elements. Those `n` elements that are not matched by your template matching `n[x]` will be processed by the default [built in template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) that does:

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

i.e. it will recursively apply templates to the descendants, until it reaches the `w` elements - for which you do have a custom template:

```
<xsl:template match="w">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@a" mode="fromone"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Why can't you do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <output>
        <one>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//w"/>
        </one>
        <x>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//n[x]//w" mode="fromtwo"/>
        </x>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w">
    <fromone>
        <xsl:value-of select="@a"/>
    </fromone>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w" mode="fromtwo">
    <fromtwo>
        <xsl:value-of select="@a"/>
    </fromtwo>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So I could also solve this by creating an empty w-matching template?

Comment: Yes, if you match the modes from the very beginning. But selective applying is both simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of a default template that captures every `n`-element without an `x`-subelement. If you apply `<xsl:apply-templates select="n"/>` in the context of an `s`-node, then none of the direct successors of `s` will have an `x`-subnode, such that your template `n[x]` will never match. As no other template matches, the default template comes into place and applies every subnode without mode.

So I'd add a template that takes care of all `n`-nodes without `x`-subelement:

```xml
<xsl:template match="n[not(x)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="n"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Applied to your sample above, it yields the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<output xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <one/>
    <x/>
</output>
<output xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <one>
        <fromone>Hello</fromone>
        <fromone>he said</fromone>
        <fromone>how are you</fromone>
        <fromone>she answered</fromone>
        <fromone>friendly</fromone>
    </one>
    <x>
        <fromtwo>he said</fromtwo>
        <fromtwo>friendly</fromtwo>
    </x>
</output>
```

Comment: This works for my simplified example here, but not for my actual file, the output for that combines all the n[x]/w/@a-contents, it gives me like <fromtwo>he said friendly</fromtwo>

Comment: edited the answer, though I think it should have worked with the previous version, too. Could you please post your actual file?